# Sortable table or spreadsheet with full, detailed 2017 UK General Election results for every constituency

Tags: election, united-kingdom, reference-request

I'm looking for a full sortable list of the results, for every constituency, ideally with as much information as possible: Turnout, # eligible voters, votes for each candidate (both # and %), winning majority (both # and %), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [a Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SGkPQqosDbVL9tSX_uMNaXPGiW2z02z2fchDezlyNss/edit#gid=0) by [Britain Elects](http://britainelects.com/ge2017/).

It includes:

- Constituency, Nation, Region
- 2015 winner, 2017 winner
- Share +/- from 2015

Unfortunately, it doesn't have the no. of eligible voters.

Comment: Just to note that for some reason, Northern Ireland (18 seats) is missing, so only 632/650 are shown.

Comment: @KennyLJ Yea, seems like it's only GB-wide constituencies are shown - `Sheet of the 2017 General Election (GB wide only).`

Answer (score 1):

The offical results are published by the Electoral Commission, on their web site https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/our-work/our-research/electoral-data. The data for the 2017 June General election is not yet available (as of June 10th)

It includes "data on electorate sizes, turnout, rejected ballots and postal votes." as well as the number of ballots cast for each candidate.