# British parliamentary election results in convenient spreadsheet form

Tags: election, united-kingdom, data-sources

The following books by F. W. S. Craig contain a treasure trove of data about British parliamentary election results:

- [British Parliamentary Election Results 1832–1885](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-349-02349-3)
- [British Parliamentary Election Results 1885–1918](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-349-02298-4)
- [British Parliamentary Election Results 1918–1949](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-349-81467-1)
- [British parliamentary election results, 1950-1970](http://catalogue.nla.gov.au/Record/1015266)

(There are probably also books too for post-1970 results that I would very much be interested in.)

I wonder if anyone has all (or any part) of the data contained in these books entered in convenient spreadsheet form?

(I am half-thinking of entering these data into spreadsheet form myself or paying someone to do it, but obviously no point doing it if someone else has already done it and is kind enough to share it with the world.)

Answer (score 1):

For all recent elections ( in last 15 years or so) this data is published in spreadsheet form by the Electoral Commision amd can be found [here](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/our-work/our-research/electoral-data). Please also see [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/19785/13484) for 2017 data. Electoral data relating to analysis of election results between 1964 -2010 and 2015 can also be downloaded from the British Election Study Website [here](http://www.britishelectionstudy.com/data/#.WVYN7p-nzqA).

Comment: Sorry, but it seems like the British Election Study data are just data from their studies (surveys and such), rather than the results of the elections.